# Trying to print with python but can't manage to find the default printer

Tags: python, django, printing

I'm working on a python/django project where i need to print a text file.

```
import win32api
import win32print


def printFile():
    filename = "path/test.txt"
    win32api.ShellExecute (0,"print",filename, '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (), ".", 0)
```

I first tried this code directly in a cmd prompt, and it worked.
I then made a py file to define the print function as it is above, but when I call it from my view, I always get the same error:

> "The default printer was not found"

I tried to put the import in the path variable, but I don't see what I did wrong, the import seems to work because I get no error calling the function, only the printer not found error.

Update :

I tried to call my print script with subprocess, execfile and some other function but to the same end, it work when i'm in a cmd shell or even django shell environement but not when called from the webapp.

I tried calling it with the printer's name, but it end up with another error telling me that the printer is malfunctionning.

Comment: It doesn't work from django because django is running on the server and the printer is not. That would be my guess. I had to do something similar, trying to find how i fixed it.

Comment: I just trying start a django shell in eclipse and run the same code and it worked just fine, kinda lost

Comment: As which user does the server process run? I guess that it has something to do with permission management in the OS. Which server do you use? Does it happen with `python manage.py runserver` or with a "real" webserver?

Comment: With a real webserver

Comment: But i does seem like a permission / env or path problem but i don't really get with it's only with the application that it fails.